# Firefox incompatibility with typed.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

*I don't really know how to call this problem of mine so change the title if you have a better idea and if you're a person with the power to do so.*

Anyway, I got this webpage [here](http://inovlancer.com/projetos/cityoffuture/) that I'm developing, it works perfectly fine but my bottom menu gets deformated and goes to the side line on firefox. It only happens on the index, I suppose it has something to do with the [Typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) that I'm using only on the index.

Here's what it looks like on chrome [image: chrome]
And what it looks like on firefox [image: firefox]

It is really geting on my nerves, I tried changing some heights and widths but it doesn't change anything.

This doesn't make any sense for me, I would really appreciate a bright mind coming with a solution for this.

TL;DR [Here](http://inovlancer.com/projetos/cityoffuture/) the bottom menu is deformated on firefox only on the index, why? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float`.

`.linhas_left`, `.linhas_right` and `.container_linhas` are `float`ing, making all following text and inline elements flow around them.

Firefox apparently treats `.menu` like an inline element in the element flow and I have no idea why that is, but here's how to fix it.
Add this to your CSS:

```
.footer
{
    clear: both;
}
```

**Edit**: It looks like this has been reported as a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=478834) in 2009 already and [too](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653355) [many](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728291) [duplicates](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739871) [have](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763035) [been](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833250) [filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133656) [so](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1073574) [far](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1152751), but it doesn't look like a fix is to be expected anytime soon.

Comment: You're a life savior.